# Output image to browser AND write to disk

Tags: php

This seems like a SUPER easy question for people who knows PHP but I can't figure out how to make this work (probably because I know VERY little about PHP). Most question related to this asks how to output an image to either browser *or* disk, but I wanna do both. See example below:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/png');

$filename = "my_written_image.png";
$png_image = imagecreatefrompng('some_fancy_image.png');
imagepng($png_image, $filename);
imagepng($png_image);

?>
```

This won't work. The image won't show in the browser, but it will work if I remove this line: `imagepng($png_image, $filename);`

I'm guessing one can only "output" one thing using `imagepng` but how will I accomplish the above?

Comment: Where are you getting the image? Is it being uploaded?

Comment: In this example the $png_image is assigned and created by using imagecreatefrompng(...)

Comment: If the image is already on the server, what disk do you want to write it to?

Comment: The reason I wanted to write it to disk again was only for demonstrating purposes. Sorry I caused such confusion, see my answer below (was a really stupid mistake on my part).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$filename = "my_written_image.png";
$png_image = imagecreatefrompng('some_fancy_image.png');
file_put_contents($filename, $image);
imagepng($png_image, $filename);
?>
```

My server is not turned on so I can't test the code but I think this should work.

Comment: This doesn't work, using this the file wont even get created! :( (You've also made a typo your $image should be $png_image)

Comment: Okay thanks to you I managed to find what was wrong. I realised there was an error before this that caused "my" solution (and yours) to fail. I will post it as a separate answer!

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems my original solution actually did work. The problem was I was using (in my real code): `if(readfile("myfile.png"))` and this will return `false` if it's not found, but it will also throw an error if `@readfile()` is not used (note the `@`). The docs said:

> an error message is printed

I didn't think this would cause the whole thing to fail. Sorry for my stupidness.